# How do I customise individual menu links?

Tags: routes, theming

I have a menu created through admin/structure/menu.

On some of the menus, I would like to place a var after the title.

I have tried placing the following in my theme template, but nothing happens.

```
 function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
   print_r($variables['element']);
 }
```

How could I just place the content of a PHP variable after the menu link title?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to add a string after the menu title, you can use the following code.

```
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'] . ' ' . t('the string you need to add'), $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

The alternative would be using the following code, which would give to who translate the string more context to translate it.

```
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l(t('!title the string you need to add', array('!title' => $element['#title'])), $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

You could also implement a preprocess function to alter the title.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $variables['element']['#title'] = t('!title the string you need to add', array('!title' => $variables['element']['#title']));
}
```

Comment: couldnt get this to work on any menus. some links are created through modules, some through views, some through the menu form in drupal. I have added the code to my template and changed mytheme to my theme name and nothing changes. Also where do I specify which menu items?